# How do you set up carrierwave with S3 to use s3_access

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I've read that carrierwave is much faster without using fog https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/261

I set up s3 access directly, but my app crashes when I try to set s3_access ... since there isn't a setter. How do I get the equivalent of fog_public = false, without fog?